# Python - how to abstract common starting/ending code

Tags: python, methods, lambda, callback

I have a bunch of methods which all look something like this:

```py
def myFunc():
    ...
    {initialise stuff}
    {do stuff}
    {finalise stuff}
    ...
```

where `{initialise stuff}` and `{finalise stuff}` are *identical* for each method, and `{do stuff}` may use variables defined in `{initialise stuff}`.

To avoid repetition, I'd like to put `{initialise stuff}` and `{finalise stuff}` in a separate method, which could be called from inside `myFunc()`. So, something like this:

```py
def wrap(innerMethod):
    vars = {initialise stuff}
    innerMethod(vars)
    {finalise stuff}

def myFunc():
    ...
    wrap(lambda vars :
        {do stuff}
    )
    ...
```

Unfortunately, it seems that [code blocks can't be passed as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211220/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-block-argument-in-python-without-defining-it-as-a-fun) in Python (unless this feature has been added in the last 2 years). Therefore, this doesn't seem to work if `{do stuff}` is longer than a single line. I could put `{do stuff}` into a separate method, but I'd rather not since:

- The `{do stuff}` code will never be reused (it is different for each method);
- It makes the program flow more confusing / less logical.

**Is there another way to put `{initialise stuff}` and `{finalise stuff}` into a separate method?**

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at decorators?

Comment: This sounds like a job for either a decorator or a context manager.

Comment: So if I use a decorator, do I still have to put the `{do stuff}` in its own method?

Comment: `{do stuff}` is kinda the part that is supposed to be _dynamic_, no? so it will have its own function but the repetitive stuff will be only decoratros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) provide the best solution - thanks to @user2357112 for the suggestion.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def wrap():
  {initialise stuff}
  yield {stuff-to-return-to-method}
  {finalise stuff}

def myFunc():
  with wrap() as vars:
    {do stuff}
```

You can even pass arguments to `wrap` and use them in the initialisation.

If you want `{finalise stuff}` to run even if the wrapped code throws an exception (which you usually do want with context managers), you should wrap the `yield` in a `try` and put the finalization in a `finally`:

```py
@contextmanager
def wrap():
  {initialise stuff}
  try:
    yield {stuff-to-return-to-method}
  finally:
    {finalise stuff}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) and `decorator`:

```
import functools

def mywrapper(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("{initialize_stuff}")
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("{finalize_stuff}")
        return result
    return wrapper

@mywrapper
def myFunc():
    print("{innerMethod}")
```

Output:

```
>>> myFunc()
{initialize_stuff}
{innerMethod}
{finalize_stuff}
```